# Case statement in group by

Tags: sql, oracle

Getting this error
ORA-12704: character set mismatch

```
SELECT name,
 YEAR,
PERIOD,
ENTITY,
CASE WHEN VALUE = 'USD Total' then 'USD' ELSE VALUE end as VALUE,
sum(amount)
from stats1
group by
name,
 YEAR,
PERIOD,
ENTITY,
CASE WHEN VALUE = 'USD Total' then 'USD' ELSE VALUE end,
''''
```

Comment: I formatted your code (which you can do by selecting all the code and pressing CTRL-K, or choosing the `{}` icon in the formatting toolbar). I don't understand the end of the query. What is with those single-quotes on the last line? Other than that - are you sure the error is thrown by this query, and not by something else? How are you running it?

Comment: I suspect that one of the values of the else part is from another character set. What you might try is use ```ELSE convert(value, 'utf8') end as VALUE ```. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/functions027.htm#SQLRF00620 for reference.

Comment: Marko's suspicion, above, may be correct. Perhaps the VALUE column stores strings in the national character set rather than the database character set. The way to test this (and to fix the problem, if this is indeed the reason for the error) is to use the `N` modifier for text literals. Namely: `case when value = N'USD Total' then N'USD' else value end` (and make sure you do the same everywhere in the query). Of course, you can also run `describe stats1` - this should tell you the data type of every column in the table.

Comment: this is working now/ case when value = N'USD Total' then N'USD' else value end

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
        name                                                            ,
        YEAR                                                            ,
        PERIOD                                                          ,
        ENTITY                                                          ,
        CASE WHEN VALUE = 'USD Total' THEN 'USD' ELSE VALUE END AS VALUE,
        SUM(amount)
FROM
        stats1
GROUP BY
        name  ,
        YEAR  ,
        PERIOD,
        ENTITY,
        VALUE
```

Comment: This is not equivalent to the OP's attempt. Grouping by `VALUE` is not the same as grouping by `case when VALUE = 'USD Total' then 'USD' else VALUE end`. If `VALUE` can have both values, `USD` in some rows and `USD Total` in other rows, then the OP wants those combined in a single group, but your re-write will have them in different groups. That is in addition to the obvious fact that your answer doesn't address the OP's question in any way (which was about a character set mismatch error).

Answer (score 0):

The below code is working but why isnt it accepting the else part....i want to pass value as it is if value is other than 'USD Total'

```
SELECT name,
 YEAR,
PERIOD,
ENTITY,
CASE WHEN VALUE = 'USD Total' then 'USD' end as VALUE,
sum(amount)
from stats1
group by
name,
 YEAR,
PERIOD,
ENTITY,
CASE WHEN VALUE = 'USD Total' then 'USD' end
```